# Error generating keys with OpenSSL on Ubuntu 22.04.4

Tags: python, ubuntu, openssl, cryptography

I have a python script with functions for generating keys, signing messages, encrypting and decrypting them.

```
def gen_keys(key_name):
    result1 = subprocess.call([
        'openssl', 'genpkey', '-algorithm', 'RSA', '-provider-path',
        '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ossl-modules', '-provider', 'legacy',
        '-out', f'{key_name}_private_key.pem'
    ])
    result2 = subprocess.call([
        'openssl', 'pkey', '-pubout', '-in',
        f'{key_name}_private_key.pem', '-out', f'{key_name}_public_key.pem'
    ])
    if result1 != 0 or result2 != 0:
        print(f"Error gen {key_name} keys")
        return False
    return True
def sign_message(key_name, message):
    with open('message.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(message)
    result = subprocess.call([
        'openssl', 'dgst', '-sha256', '-sign',
        f'{key_name}_private_key.pem', '-out', 'signature.sig', 'message.txt'
    ])
    if result != 0:
        print(f"Error signing message with {key_name}'s private key")
        return False
    return True


def verify_signature(key_name, message_path, signature_path):
    result = subprocess.call([
        'openssl', 'dgst', '-sha256',
        '-verify', f'{key_name}_public_key.pem', '-signature',
        signature_path, message_path
    ])
    return result == 0


def encrypt_message(key_name, message_path, encrypted_message_path):
    result = subprocess.call([
        'openssl', 'cms', '-encrypt', '-in', message_path,
        '-out', encrypted_message_path, '-recip', f'{key_name}_public_key.pem',
        '-keyopt', 'rsa_padding_mode:oaep', '-cipher', 'aes-256-cbc'
    ])
    if result != 0:
        print(f"Error encrypting message with {key_name}'s public key")
        return False
    return True


def decrypt_message(key_name, encrypted_message_path, decrypted_message_path):
    result = subprocess.call([
        'openssl', 'cms', '-decrypt', '-in', encrypted_message_path, '-out',
        decrypted_message_path, '-recip', f'{key_name}_private_key.pem'
    ])
    if result != 0:
        print(f"Error decrypting message with {key_name}'s private key")
        return False
    return True
```

Then I use keys for verifying signatures, decrypting and encrypting messages, but I get this error:

```
Verified OK
Verified OK
Could not read recipient certificate file from client_private_key.pem
4027E61AB47F0000:error:1608010C:STORE routines:ossl_store_handle_load_result:unsupported:../crypto/store/store_result.c:151:
Unable to load recipient certificate file
Error decrypting message with client's private key
Could not read recipient certificate file from server_private_key.pem
40575BD9937F0000:error:1608010C:STORE routines:ossl_store_handle_load_result:unsupported:../crypto/store/store_result.c:151:
Unable to load recipient certificate file
Error decrypting message with server's private key
```

I checked if files are in path (they are), I have full access to them. So I don't know why I always receiving error like this, but I'm not an expert in OpenSSL